# Guardar XML en servidor en base a consulta php

Tags: xml, php7

Tengo una tabla "inmuebles" donde, mediante una consulta php, muestro los inmuebles activos que tengo en estos momentos. En cada fila puedo editar el inmueble, borrar etc... pero quiero tener un button en cada fila que me permita guardar los datos de ese inmueble en un archivo xml y lo guarde en una carpeta del server... la pregunta es si se podría generar el XML simplemente dándole a ese botón.

Comment: claro que se puede dale una mirada a xmlwritter() y veras que es sencillo generar la estructura e incluir los datos en el.

Comment: He estado mirando xmlwriter y parece bastante interesante. El problema que tengo es que no sé como poder generar el xml desde cada fila de la tabla, es decir, si quiero crear un xml del inmueble 2º que aparece en la tabla, que le pueda dar click y que me lo guarde en server...